# No Suitable Driver Found Exception: Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, jersey

i am working on `jax-rs(jersey)` and want to connect to database by using hibernate. my projects works perfectly fine when i debug it as java application but as i run my project on server it gives No suitable driver found for `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample`

[here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivrdT.png)

the sql exception is here

> ```
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:208)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
> ```

Comment: have you included [mysql jdbc driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/6.0.5) in your classpath?

Answer (score 2):

You have to download the [MySQL Connector/J](http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.18/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar) and add it to your class path

If you are using maven you can use this dependency :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.18</version>
</dependency>
```